# Can Markdown mode help with generating the 2nd line in a Markdown table?

Tags: markdown-mode, table

When I write a table like

```
| Syntax      | Description | More columns ... |
| ----------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| Header      | Title       | .                |
| Paragraph   | Text        | .                |
```

in [Markdown mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) I start writing the first line

```
| Syntax      | Description | More columns ... |
```

and then, for the second line

```
| ----------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
```

I was hoping Markdown Mode could generate it for me, but I haven't found a function/command for it.

Can Markdown Mode (or another Markdown package) do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Try hitting TAB

I started with:

```markdown
| id | name | phone | email |
```

Then I typed "|-" on the next line.

```markdown
| id | name | phone | email |
|-
```

Then I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `markdown-cycle`):

```markdown
| id | name | phone | email |
|----|------|-------|-------|
|    |      |       |       |
```

Emacs generated the horizontal lines and an empty row to fill in.  I found it by playing around.  Hitting TAB works in org-mode with its tables too.

Comment: Interesting! Doesn't seem to work for me. Which command gets for you executed when you hit TAB (in a Markdown buffer).

Comment: @halloleo - The function that is bound to TAB is `markdown-cycle` in this context.  I was able to `M-x markdown-cycle` when my cursor was after the "|-" to get the same result just now.

Comment: Thanks! That works for me! (Have added it to the answer.)